# Why does Lambda generate identical cryptographic keys after initialization and how to fix it?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, jce

I've noticed something weird when generating key pairs from AWS Lambda - every time I run the code it generates identical keys. I am aware that Lambda containers are frozen after each invocation and this is probably why the underlying JCE classes are loaded from memory and keep their initial state. The code in question is relatively simple:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

return new RSAKey.Builder(rsaPublicKey).privateKey(rsaPrivateKey)
            .keyID(kid).keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
```

I tried both the vanilla provider and Bouncy Castle but the result is the same - identical key pairs when Lambda is "warm". Once the container is terminated and restarted from a "cold" state, I get a new and different set of keys.

I'm also using AWS Cognito and the service is served through both API Gateway and CloudFront.

Any ideas how to "refresh" the underlying JCE classes?

Comment: Does `keyPairGen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom())` help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I've noticed that it is related to my authentication session and after logging out of Cognito and logging back in, the generated key pairs are different. Something, somewhere gets cached and caching is definitely turned off in API Gateway.

Comment: Got it - it's definitely CloudFront!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the culprit was actually CloudFront. Even with API caching turned off in API Gateway, CloudFront still caches the responses for some API requests.

If someone comes across the same problem, the solution is to "bust" the CloudFront cache by appending a query parameter to the request URL:

```
GET /api/generateKeyPair?timestamp=1507843759370
```

Comment: For CloudFront distributions that you create, you need to configure CloudFront correctly for your application.  The default behavior is to cache responses with no `Cache-Control` headers for 24 hours.